# PHP file upload from html form

Tags: php

can someone take a look at this?
I'm trying to do a very basic file upload to a folder that is within my project directory with php. This is what I've put together but it's just not working. I have enabled file uploads in php.ini and my local server is working fine.

I'm using OSX and running on localhost with apache. I'm wondering if you are supposed to upload to a file on the machine. I'm not sure if you are allowed to upload to a folder in the project.

Here is the error:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /Users/jakeaddis/sites/file_copy/index.php on line 14

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpAHX3Ak' to 'uploads/' in /Users/jakeaddis/sites/file_copy/index.php on line 14

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $file_name = $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
    $file_size = $_FILES["upload"]["size"];
    $tempname = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];


    if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, "uploads/" . $file_name)) {
        echo "Sucessful!";
    } else {
        echo "Failed!";
    }

}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #outer {
                width: 500px;
                height: 600px;
                margin: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <form id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 'just not working'? Please specify.

Comment: if you are using linux may be there is directory permissions problem

Comment: is this variable file_name have an extension with it?

Comment: `$file_name = $_POST["filename"];` - you cannot get the file name in this way. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: is it `tmp_name` or  `tempnam`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why do you ever need to take as input the file name ( i.e. input field with `filename` name ) ?

Comment: I need to save it to a different location, with move_uploaded_file() it gives it a temporary name then moves it to new location and assigns it's original name to it. Should I do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find error for `tmp_name`, you are using `tempnam` which is wrong. Use

```
$tempname = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
```

Check more detail in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Also add `name` for submit, to get value in `$_POST` as you are checking `$_POST["submit"]`

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: thanks, I made those changes. It's still not working for me.

Comment: @Addis16 : what error you are getting ? Also check folder permission

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /Users/jakeaddis/sites/file_copy/index.php on line 14

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpAHX3Ak' to 'uploads/' in /Users/jakeaddis/sites/file_copy/index.php on line 14

Comment: If it is a image file then use .png or .jpg, use any extesion of file.

Comment: This is why I'm wondering if the folder has to be outside the project directory. but that seem's odd to me.

Comment: So add a . ".png" etc... to $tempname and $ filename?

Comment: No need to change anything in `tmp_name` , just add in `$file_name` ?